# ¿Como puedo autocompletar Forms en Django con las ForeignKey?

Tags: python, django

Mi intención es que el Form tome automáticamente el usuario_id que esta en sesión y el libro_id que se esta solicitando, y que la ventana modal muestre esta información pero con el campo de cantidad_dias editable para luego confirmar el préstamo.

```
# Model
class Prestamos (models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    libro_id = models.ForeignKey(Libros, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    usuario_id = models.ForeignKey(Usuarios, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cantidad_dias = models.SmallIntegerField('Cantidad de dias a prestar', default= 5)
    fecha_prestamo = models.DateField('Fecha de prestamo', auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    fecha_vencimiento = models.DateField('Fecha de vencimiento de la reserva', auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, null = True, blank = True)
    estado = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name= 'Prestado')
 
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Prestamo'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Prestamos'
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f'Prestamo de libro {self.libro_id} por {self.usuario_id}'
```

```
# Form
 class PrestamoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['libro_id'].queryset = Libros.objects.filter(estado=True, cantidad__gte = 1)
        for field in iter (self.fields):
            self.fields[field].widget.attrs.update({
                'class': 'form-control'
            })
            self.fields['libro_id'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
            self.fields['usuario_id'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
            self.fields['cantidad_dias'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = False
 
    class Meta:
         model = Prestamos
         fields = ['libro_id', 'usuario_id', 'cantidad_dias']
         exclude = ['fecha_prestamo','fecha_vencimiento', 'estado']
 
    def clean_libro(self):
        libro = self.cleaned_data['libro_id']
        if libro.cantidad < 1:
            raise ValidationError('No hay libro disponibles.')
        return libro
```

```
 
# View
class RegistrarPrestamo(CreateView):
     model = Prestamos
     success_url = reverse_lazy('libros:disp_libro')
     template_name = 'libro/prestar_libro.html'
     form_class = PrestamoForm
```

```
#Url
path('libro/prestar-libro/', login_required(RegistrarPrestamo.as_view()), name = 'prestar_libro')
```

Lo único que logre hacer es esto pero es un form editable.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No se mucho de django pero te puedo guiar en la lógica si quieres

Comment: Si quieres realizar una creación de un elemento con el modal, es necesario que lo hagas con ajax request. La vista genérica CreateView esta diseñada para retornar un template con un formulario, y redirigir al realizar una petición POST extiosa. Desde mi punto de vista, es más fácil recibir la petición POST con una view en forma de función. Con respecto a como autocompletar los campos de input, creo que es sencillo debido a que la página de fondo representa información del libro al que corresponde el modal, entonces es tan simple como en esa plantilla poner `value= {{libro.pk}}` en el modal.